# Linking organ pedals to a keyboard

Tags: keyboard, organ

Having 'rescued' the bass pedals from an old organ, I wish to use them as add-ons to my keyboards, when the bassist can't make it.What is a simple way to connect them so that they work through the keyboard, or sound module? I guess MIDI may be the way to go, but any advice from anyone who has successfully achieved this would be good.

Comment: Should be a fun project.  If you can, please post a pic when you complete it.  I was thinking that while you're installing midi-compatible sensors, why not add some more so pedal actions also, say, run a LED display?

Comment: You mean like a mini (midi) Blackpool illuminations? No-one would see them, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Far less expensive is a $45 [MIDI-CPU](http://store.highlyliquid.com/products/midi-cpu).  If your pedalboard already has switches, great.  Otherwise buy reed switches, diodes, and magnets from digikey or jameco.  The forums for the MIDI-CPU explain every step and snag of rebuilding your own pedalboard, from soldering on up.  (I'm just a satisfied customer.)

Comment: Finally got round to it almost a year later! The CPU pcb works well, certainly with one of my keyboards. Total cost around £50 !! Not complaining at that !!

Comment: No apology needed, Tim.  I finished my pedalboard almost a year ago, but the console's still under construction.  The only thing slower to restore than organs is wooden sailboats.

Comment: All I need now is to make it work with my Roland FP2, which has GM sounds - MIDId, it'll only make a piano sound.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't done this, but there are kits from organ-building companies that enable you to install a sensor under each footpedal, all of which are connected to a MIDI interface.

After a Google search, I found a link to [this product at Classical MIDI Works in Canada](http://www.midiworks.ca/index.php/products/details/146/59/midi-scanners/single-keyboard/pedalboard/midi-pedalboard-switch-kit-w/mksc-4a).

There are also several companies that sell complete, stand-alone MIDI bass pedal controller units that range from one octave to two-and-a-half octaves. [Roland](http://www.roland.com/products/en/PK-25A/), [Nord](http://www.nordkeyboards.com/main.asp?tm=Products&clpm=Nord_Pedal_Keys_27), [Keith McMillen](http://www.keithmcmillen.com/12step/tour), and [Hammond](http://hammondorganco.com/products/accessories-a-parts/accessories/pedalspedal-boardsfoot-switch/) are four of them.

Comment: @Wheat-thanks for the info. The 1st is over expensive, and since I already have the pedals, I'm looking for a project. (Recycling at its best!)

Comment: I think the first link I sent you to (costing US $550) IS the route to the least expensive project. Good luck.