# Lateral alignment of pedalboard to keyboards

Tags: organ

How should an organ's (61-key) manuals align with its pedalboard, left to right?

- Symmetrically?
- By centering a D from the manual on the middle D pedal?

Neither the AGO nor the British online specifications say explicitly.  The British [diagram](http://www.organworks.co.uk/brit_console_dimensions_white.pdf) seems to self-contradictorily suggest *both* of these options.  (I'm in the New World, so I'd prefer a north american standard.)

Related: [Linking organ pedals to a keyboard](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/14159/linking-organ-pedals-to-a-keyboard)

Comment: Of course, not all pedalboards have the same number of pedals; they cover different note ranges. They also have different physical layouts (radial curved, radial flat, straight). I imagine that these factors have to be taken into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of the above.  If the keys and manuals are close to spec in width, then symmetry and D-D alignment can be true at the same time.  AGO spec does say, "Left to right location: Centered under the manuals."